# how to get length of the characters in a array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

so like imagine I have an array like this

```
names = ["Alex", "David", "Hanna"]
```

so I want to get the length of the characters like Alex is 4 characters long and If I get an odd length I want to show that as an output. I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Use the `.length` property of the array element.

Comment: Isn't Alex just 4 characters long?

Comment: Why are there so many questions about odd length names today?

Comment: sorry my bad its 4 characters long, and I did try .length but it returns the elements of the array

Comment: It sounds like you forgot to index the array, so you got the length of the array instead of the element.

Comment: `names[0].length` is 4

Comment: uhh sorry I'm kinda bad at english, how do I index the array?

Comment: oh so I cant like loop through it to check all of the names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.filter` method to filter the results

```js
const names = ["Alex", "David", "Hanna"]
names.filter(name => name.length % 2 !== 0) // ['David', 'Hanna']
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Santonu to SO, you can do the following:

```js
const names = ["Alex", "David", "Hanna"];

for (const name of names) {
  console.log(name.length);
}
```

This will iterate every name of the array and log you the length.

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = ["Alex", "David", "Hanna"]
array.forEach(item => {if(item.length%2 == 1)  console.log(item)});
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript) for loop in javascript.